# Simple haskell string manage

Tags: string, haskell

Theres is a little problem I want to solve with Haskell:
let substitute a function that change all of the wildcards in a string for one concrete parameter. The function has de signature of:

```
subs :: String -> String -> String -> String
-- example:
-- subs 'x' "x^3 + x + sin(x)" "6.2" will generate
--          "6.2^3 + 6.2 + sin(6.2)"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [Text.Regex](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-compat-0.95.1) package.

Your example might look something like this:

```
import Text.Regex(mkRegex, subRegex)

subs :: String -> String -> String -> String
subs wildcard input value = subRegex (mkRegex wildcard) input value
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://bluebones.net/2007/01/replace-in-haskell/ for an example which looks exactly as the piece of code you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **text-format-simple** library for such cases:

```
import Text.Format
format "{0}^3 + {0} + sin({0})" ["6.2"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions (`Text.Regex.Posix`) and search-replace for `/\Wx\W/` (Perl notation).  Simply replacing `x` to `6.2` will bring you trouble with `x + quux`.

[Haskell Regex Replace](http://lukeplant.me.uk/blog.php?id=1107301690) for more information (I think this should be imported to SO.

For extra hard-core you could parse your expression as AST and do the replacement on that level.

Comment: @paullrulan: I hope you aren't trying to do symbolic math WITHOUT a proper parser/AST. Strings are a nightmare for that... Please tell me you are not trying to substitute variables lexically instead of with an AST...